# Setting values in a child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In following scenario I have a very simple child component (arrow component) that acts like a counter. The counter can increment a simple value. What if the parent wants to set that counter to x? The obvious answer would be just have a parameter that you set to x. But as my variable in the parent component is a hook, it would be read only. Would you then have to add a parameter for both the getter and setter variable on the child? And then the child would work on those two variables? Or what is best practice here? Or is there some way to transfer the complete hook to the child? It is really not beautiful that you must add two parameters to the child in my world.

```
const App = props => {
  const resetChildCounter = () => {
    alert("what to do here");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child />
      <button onClick={resetChildCounter}>
        Reset child counter from parent
      </button>
      <button onClick={resetChildCounter}>Set child counter to 5</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = props => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>Counter is: {counter}</span>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCounter(counter + 1);
        }}
      >
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Call child]

Comment: you can move your increment button to parent so you don't need to pass setter to child component.

Comment: This is just a sample to illustrate my problem. I would like to make a self maintained child component with much more stuff than a simple button. Plus I would have multiple counters with each of their own state,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Child` component acts like a "hybrid" component, it acts as a [controlled component **and** an uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components).

A simple implementation of a hybrid component looks like this:

```
const NOOP = () => {}

const Child = ({ initial = 0, onChange = NOOP }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(initial);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCounter(initial);
  }, [initial]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(counter);
  }, [onChange, counter]);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>Counter is: {counter}</span>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(p => p + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

[image: Edit Call child]

In this case, as stated by the OP:

> I would like to make a self-maintained child component with much more stuff than a simple button.

You get a stand-alone component with a controlled feature.

Comment: I think this is much better. But does it have a problem? As I understand it your component listens for changes on the parameter (correct me if I am wrong). So when the parent changes that parameter to say lets say 5, the child's counter would now be 5. Then the child start incrementing that value to lets say 8. Now the parent want to set that value back to 5. However your event would not get fired, because you set the marameter to 5 again and the child does not get triggered?

Comment: Yeah works like a charm. I like this approach much better. More self contained!

Answer (score 0):

You're correct.

If you need to set it from the parent, you need to store it as a state of the parent, not the child. And if you need to use it on the child, you need to pass it down to the child. Finally, if you need to set it from the child as well, you don't do it directly, but through a setter prop passed down from the parent.

> It is really not beautiful that you must add two parameters to the child in my world.

If you have a state in either parent or child, and then if it's possible for you to mutate it from both sides, that is more ugly. It will break the philosophy of React.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Appreciated. I eneded with Dennis answer as it is more self contained.